# Calculating car's acceleration from change in angle of hanging object?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, kinematics, acceleration, velocity

The question essentially is based on a situation like this-

A car has a small object hung from the cieling on a string (apparently at an angle of 0 degrees to the ceiling).

The car is accelerating and the object is now hanging at a 30 degree angle (to the ceiling). 
How would I figure out how much the car is accelerating.

PS - This is homework but Im stuck and would appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Edit: changed angle from 45 to 30.

Comment: How is your trigonometry?

Comment: alright i guess. im assuming thats a hint at what i should be looking at?

Comment: check out my answer, feel free to ask if you don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can be tackled using the equivalence principle.  This basically means that the accelerating car can be thought of from the perspective of the hanging object, as a horizontal gravitational field, with an acceleration equal to that of the car.

Therefore we effectively have two forces acting on the object.  One downwards of $mg$, the other horizontally of $ma$, where a is the acceleration of the car.

The angle of the resultant force is given by $\tan \theta = \frac{m a}{m g} = \frac{a}{g}$

Therefore $a = g \tan \theta$

Comment: Won't the angle also depend on the density of the air and the object?

Comment: @Aniansh so long as the object is denser than air it won't.

Answer (score 2):

This is a neat example because the object makes its own force triangle - it's being pulled down by gravity and sideways by the car's acceleration. And the 45° angle means that the forces are equal.

Comment: Ahh I see. The real question has a 13 degree angle.  I get it when they are equal, but how would I forumalte the link between the force-acceleration and force-gravity now.

Comment: Note for context: I changed the angle from 45 to 30.

Comment: + @sri: Just make a right triangle by drawing a vertical line from the attachment point, and a horizontal line from the object. Measure the height h and base b of the right triangle. Then just do the proportion. Acceleration a is to gravity g as b is to h.

Answer (score 1):

[D'Alembert's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_principle) can be used to convert any dynamic system into a static one by converting accelerations into equal but opposite inertia forces.

Hence in the diagram below there is a horizontal force acting to the right with value of $m a$. Now all you have to do is the force balance in *x*-axis and *y*-axis to get $T$ and $a$

[image: FBD]